# query plan cost confusion

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan, query-planner

the following query with different limit count, make out different query plan and very different scan rows :

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `funds_cash_apply` WHERE 1 and `id` > '0' and `channel` in ('70','81') and `state` = '1' and `state_pay` = '0' and `create_time` < '1447063200' order by id asc limit 50 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: funds_cash_apply
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_state_state_e
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 373619
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `funds_cash_apply` WHERE 1 and `id` > '0' and `channel` in ('70','81') and `state` = '1' and `state_pay` = '0' and `create_time` < '1447063200' order by id asc limit 5000 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: funds_cash_apply
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_state_state_e
          key: idx_state_state_e
      key_len: 1
          ref: const
         rows: 6652
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the table with Indexes :

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_water_no` (`water_no`,`state`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_kdt_id` (`kdt_id`,`state`,`create_time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_batch_id` (`batch_water_no`,`state`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_cp_uid` (`cp_uid`,`state`,`create_time`),
  KEY `idx_acct_no` (`acct_no`,`state`,`create_time`),
  KEY `idx_state_state_e` (`state`,`state_exception`) USING BTREE
```

why different limit (50 vs 500) make different query plan, and the scan rows have great change？

Comment: try explain extended ... and show warnings; to see more information about the query plans

Comment: Also you might want to check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html